# sending hexadecimal file data using post to different domain

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to send this form of the request using multipart form data, by manually constructing the headers. Also for this file what will be the content/mime type. When I created this form of the request the request reached the server, but the data received there is null. Also I get an error message for cross domain request as it's not a jsonp. Is there a way to accomplish this as its a post request. Java is used as server-side.

Answer (score 0):

For your Cross-Domain request, you will need to add the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) headers to the server: something like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. Not entirely sure where this would go in Java servers, but if you have previously set headers before for the server, the CORS header would go along with that. I'm not entirely sure about sending raw binary via JavaScript. Perhaps someone else knows better.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just perform xhr POST/PUT request. But first get the file into an input.

Here is a put example I found in one my old project:

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input')
const file = fileInput.files[0]
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.onerror = (e) => {
  console.log(e)
}

xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', (e) => {
  // handle notifications about upload progress: e.loaded / e.total
  const { loaded, total } = e
  console.log(`${loaded} / ${total}`)
}, false)

xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299) {
      // upload completed
    }
  }
}

xhr.open('PUT', 'linktoupload', true)
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
xhr.send(file)
```

Comment: if I have to pass a file and a redirection url to teh rest method, how will this look like?

Comment: The file you get from the browser thru an `<input type="file"/>`, redirection you can put it in `xhr.onreadystatechange` from the response or something.